# Highchart bubble-chart : Show Y-Axis value as numeric range

Tags: highcharts, range, bubble-chart, yaxis

I have one Bubble Highchart and need to display Y-Axis price value as price range like '1-10', 11-20', '21-30'

But I am not able to achieve the same.

How can I achieve this?

Hello ppotaczek, Thank you very much for your quick response. I am trying achieve the bubble chart with below screen-shot.

[Please refer this screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUaxW.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve] when asking questions, without that it makes it difficult to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `formatter` function:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    tickInterval: 25,
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.value > 0) {
        return this.value - 24 + ' - ' + (this.value);
      }
      return this.value;
    }
  },
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3rqdn5pj/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Hello ppotaczek, Thank you very much for your quick response. I am trying achieve the bubble chart with below screen-shot. Please refers to screen-show https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLDm8.png

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam Dabhi, here you can find an example how to create this type of chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vfx94md/

Comment: Hello ppotaczek,
Thank you.

I have taken reference from your example.
I need to add more series in chart,
Lets say for Brand-1 and Brand-2 for Shirts.

I have done some experiments on your example but can't able to achieve the same.
Please refers to https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUaxW.png

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam Dabhi, in this case, you should use Grouped Categories plugin: http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/ Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/601eptc4/

Comment: Hello ppotaczek, Thank you again. Exactly, Using **grouped categories** method, I have achieved the requirement. And one more question please, Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Hello ppotaczek, I have accepted your answer, very helpful, Thanks. I am experimenting on SVGRenderer.

Comment: Hello ppotaczek,Thanks, I have did some experiments on SVGRenderer. Now, I trying to implement the same in vaadin-flow chart version-6.1.0, But I am facing some problems in achieving the same, Is it possible to achieve the same in vaadin-flow ?

Comment: I do not know vaadin-flow chart, so I will not be able to help you. I think you should open new topic on stackoverflow. If you will have any future questions about Highcharts I will try to help.

Comment: Hello ppotaczek,Thank you very very much.
I will open new topic about same on stackoverflow.
Actually vaadin-flow chart internally uses Highcharts, So I think you may have any idea about it. :)

Comment: Hello ppotaczek,

I have posted question the same question on vaadin-forum.

Thanks